# Scale matplotlib window to match content

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, resize

I am looking for a way to scale this plot/window, so that it is readable. I can manually adjust the window size, though I would want to have this happen automatically, depending on the size of the plot.

[image: Plot image]

Comment: Well, you would have to calculate the number of entries x font size + some overhead and then choose your figure size/dpi accordingly. This will easily create huge plots for increasing bar numbers. What is your upper limit of the number of bars? And you should provide [a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not just an image.

Comment: Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. Take a minute to read -> [How to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks